# How to use GetColor function using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Could you please help me to understand , How to use the `Getcolor()` Google App script .

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this code:

```
function get_color(){
var calendar = CalendarApp.getAllCalendars()

for(i=0;i<calendar.length;i++)
 {
  Logger.log(calendar[i].getColor())

 }
}
```

This will result to:

[image]

To get the calendar color, you need to have a given calendar on the variable before you can get its color. like this code:

```
function get_color(){
var calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().getColor()
Logger.log(calendar)
}
```

Hope this helps.